# Append an XML node without its children using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I'm trying to copy anode to be a child node for another node. I'm using the following syntax (with *lxml*)

```
nodeX.append(nodeY)
```

The thing is, this appends "*nodeY*" along with its child nodes which I needn't

**Question**: *How to append a node without its child nodes?*

**Update**: *Clarification*

Like in VBScript, one would write

```
nodeX.appendChild(nodeY.cloneNode(False))
```

But with Python, you need three lines of code rather than one

```
for node in nodeY:
    nodeY.remove(node)
nodeX.append(nodeY)
```

So is there a similar thing in Python?

Comment: Remove the children of `nodeY` before appending it to `nodeX`. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for the reply. But actually I was looking for a way to do this directly with **one line of code** like in *VBScript*, one would write `nodeX.appendChild(nodeY.cloneNode(False))`. Another thing, if this is not possible, is there a way to *remove children with one line of code rather than a loop*?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's one line of code? With a loop it would take two lines to remove the children.

Comment: actually *three*; *one* for the appending and *two* for the removing ;)

Comment: One, two or three: why does it matter?

Comment: What about the `clear()` method‽ Still not one line but as @mzjn asked: why does it matter?

Comment: @BlackJack, just because it looks **more neat**. Especially when you do this multiple times in your code. I mean *anyone would go for less lines of code* whenever possible. And I saw this this in VBSCript, so I wondered if the same thing can be in Python.

Comment: I don't think it is always necessarily true that "anyone would go for less lines of code whenever possible". The 3-line solution may not be "neat", but IMHO you could argue that it is more explicit and readable and therefore more pythonic ("Explicit is better than implicit", "Readabilty counts" as per the Zen of Python).

Comment: When you do something involving several lines multiple times in your code then you simply make a function out of it. If less lines of code means an unreadable mess of weird operators and implicit ”magic” behaviour and it needs an uber expert in the language several tens of minutes to figure out a one liner then not enyone would go for less lines of code. Especially not Python coders. As mzjn already recited: Readability counts.